# Atom built on Node.js isn't that a recipe for performance flaw?

Tags: node.js, performance, web-applications, architecture

**Note:** This is not an attempt to bash Atom in any way. These are the  questions I had and it's overall about the choice of Tech Web instead of a Native one.
This is me trying to understand the goal of it, and if it's a solid tool to use in general.

( I have Atom, and I use it sometimes - *test driving* - )

- Why wouldn't they make it native which would be faster and solid?
- Is Atom focused on entry level Web Developers? Is it supposed to be cool instead of functional?
- Is it a reliable and solid tool for "real" / heavey programming (with languages like C, C++, Java, etc)?
- Yes it's at its begining but why would they go with web tech (node.js) to start a product that would turn out to be slower than with native tech?
  It can't even handle big files!
- Why is Github advertising Atom (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y7aEiVwBAdk) as a tool for programming machines (rockets and low-level programming) with Javascript!!!
- And again: Is it supposed to be cool instead of functional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- making it native means you need to compile it to use it. Since one of the goals of Atom is to make a hackable (to the core) code editor, making it in javascript, css, and html allows people to use it \ changing it without compiling any code which allows a quicker flow. Since it's more of a code editor+ than an IDE, basic functionality isn't harmed so much by the performance difference.
- no. It's meant for real engineers. the kind that wants to mess with the code editor they work with and tweak it to their needs. This approach allows you to create extensions a lot easier than standard IDEs and code editors.
- yup. **real** programmers usually do **real** programming. It doesn't matter if you use notepad or whatever. Actually, a lot of programmers prefer the simplest text editors (and some don't). One of the reasons programmers give for that is that it keeps them sharp on all the little things that IDEs usually do for you.
- Node is an exciting JavaScript language for web development that has been growing in popularity in recent years. It started out for small development projects and has since penetrated the enterprise and can be seen in large companies like Microsoft, eBay, LinkedIn, Yahoo, WalMart, Uber, Oracle, and several more. Most of them actually improved their performances since the move. Just a few examples [taken from the **MEAN Machine book** by **Chris Sevilleja and Holly Lloyd**]:

  - Yahoo started experimenting with Node back in 2010. At first they just used it for small things like file uploads, and now they use Node to handle nearly 2 million requests per minute. They have noted increases in speed and a simpler development process.
  - LinkedIn began developing the server side of their mobile app entirely with Node. They were previously using Ruby, but since the switch they have seen huge increases in performance, ranging from 2 to 10 times faster.
  - PayPal has recently jumped onboard and began migrating some of their Java code to Node. They began experimenting with just their Account Overview page, but once they saw a 35% speed increase and half the amount of time spent on development, they started moving all sites to Node.js.
- It's just a commercial. It's suppose to pay tribute to old technology commericals like the AOL commercial from 1999 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1npzZu83AfU
- It's supposed to be both. For a more detailed answer, read the previous bullet which answered the question the first time you asked it ;-).